# I want to see the SQL generated by an ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging, linq-to-entities

when working with rails one can see the sql generated by active record - is such functionality possible with an asp.net mvc application?

I have added this extra text to meet the standards so just ignore it (perhaps my question was too short)

Comment: How about using a SQL profiling tool to see what is going behind ?

Comment: you can set a breakpoint in the application while debugging and see the sql query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I highly recommend the [Glimpse project](http://getglimpse.com/).  It gives you a huge amount of insight into your application including the sql that is being run on the server by EF.  Just install it from Nuget and you are up and running quickly.

[image]

Comment: Hey there, thanks for this. I installed glimpse and it pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Is there anything else I can add to this to make it considered the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can install this brilliant tool: http://miniprofiler.com. It was designed by the team at Stack Overflow.

I use it with all my projects. You will get this displayed on every page load:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net MVC supports many more data access methods than just an Active Record, and gives them all equal or near-equal footing. That means that special tooling within ASP.Net MVC itself to view generated sql from just one of them would not fit well in the platform.

That said, since you didn't bother to tell us what data provider you're using it's probably linq-to-sql. If that is the case, you can view the generated sql using the information available here:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386961.aspx

Comment: I actually don't know what db or dataprovider I'm using - I got a demo off the web and when I remove all connection strings and references to entity framework from the webconfig the app still executes it's crud work perfectly. I can't find any other database connection in any other part of the project. very puzzled